# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent whereBetween not working as expected

Tags: php

I have to get rows within a range of passed symbol no.

[Image of Table from where query is to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2TSl.png)

Query:

```
Mark::select('users_id', 'symbol_no', 'mark_obtained')
        ->where('subject_trade_id', 2)
        ->whereBetween('symbol_no', [100, 1000])
        ->orderBy('symbol_no')
        ->get();
```

This query returns no data, but I was expecting total 9 rows form the query.
If I dump the query, I find the query as expected.

[Query Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXppP.png)

If I run the generated query to `mysql` then it woks fine.

Again, if I change the symbol no. range to something like this:

```
Mark::select('users_id', 'symbol_no', 'mark_obtained')
        ->where('subject_trade_id', 2)
        ->whereBetween('symbol_no', [10, 1011])
        ->orderBy('symbol_no')
        ->get();
```

It returns 2 rows this time, and this output is also wrong.

If I try changing symbol no. range and query like this:

```
Mark::select('users_id', 'symbol_no', 'mark_obtained')
        ->where('subject_trade_id', 2)
        ->whereBetween('symbol_no', [101, 200])
        ->orderBy('symbol_no')
        ->get();
```

Now it works fine as expected.

Comment: Can you please provide information about any error you receive or why this code is not working for you?

Comment: 1st of all sorry, i posted incomplete questing for first time. Now its complete so you can know actual problem now.
It doesn't return any error. Just bank collection object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the problem**

By mistake the symbol_no column was defined as varchar() which had to be int() so, whereBetween() was being unable to return expected data.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem.. Could you please check "symbol_no" field type in database table, It should be number/integer.

Comment: Thanks @AKO you are right, column field type was the cause of problem. It took couple of hours to find the problem.